# How to convert LinkedHashMap to a custom object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a 2 topics on my Kafka Consumer side: topic A and topic B. Both are going to same method. The details of method as below;

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerService {

    @KafkaListener(topics = { "topic-a", "topic-b" }, groupId = "X-consumer")
    public <T> void listenX(Response<T> msg) {
        log.info("MSG arrived to consumer");
        KafkaMessageDTO<TokenMobieDTO> test = msg.getData();
```

---

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class KafkaMessageDTO<T> {

    @JsonProperty("object")
    private T object;

    @JsonProperty("header")
    private HttpHeaders headers;

}
```

I always send that msg variable type is `KafkaMessageDTO<TokenMobieDTO>` to that method. Trying to extract object from KafkaMessageDTO (`kafkaMessageDTO.getObject()`) but unfortunately, I am not able to do that.

In debugging, I am able to see the values and looks like data is perfectly match as below
[image]

How can I convert msg object to KafkaMessageDTO object? While I am trying to convert that, I am receiving this error

```
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.token.dto.TokenMobieDTO (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
```

I have tried to mapping but like data doesn't contain List, I wasn't able to iterate. Problem still exists.

Comment: Do you define anywhere that the message objects should be converted to your custom type? Jackson cannot know what type your `@JsonProperty("object")` field is – you need to tell it

Comment: @knittl yes, I define it in here `KafkaMessageDTO<TokenMobieDTO> test = msg.getData();` In this example T should be `KafkaMessageDTO<TokenMobieDTO> `

Comment: `T` has nothing to do with how the object is deserialized from JSON. Deserialization happens before the object is constructed and initialized, not when the field is accessed. Without telling Jackson the type, it will always fall back to `LinkedHashMap` for JSON objects (i.e. `{...}`)

Comment: So how can I handle that? Could you give me some examples, please?

Comment: A quick search turned up those posts; I don't know enough about the Kafka listeners to judge which would apply: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51096351/112968, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61430128/112968, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70216775/112968, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55825642/112968 – you want to look for "polymorphic JSON deserialization" or similar. Note that Jackson can also convert a `Map` to a custom object (that could be a simple, viable workaround for you)

Comment: @knittl thanks a lot for your help but unfortunately none of them works well for my case. I have multiple topics and I need to use JsonSerializer/JsonDeserializer as a config. If there is another way to configure only `KafkaConsumerService` that might help. If you have another opinion, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can convert the map with Jackson to your custom type. This will be inefficient (JSON is first parsed to a linked hash map, hash map is then converted), but it should work:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerService {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @KafkaListener(topics = { "topic-a", "topic-b" }, groupId = "X-consumer")
    public <T> void listenX(Response<T> msg) {
        log.info("MSG arrived to consumer");
        final KafkaMessageDTO<LinkedHashMap> test = msg.getData();
        final TokenMobieDTO dto = objectMapper.convertValue(
                test.getObject(),
                TokenMobieDTO.class);

        // ..
```

(There are better approaches)

Resources:

- [Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Answer (score -2):

The issue in your code is related to generic type erasure in Java. When you try to extract the object from KafkaMessageDTO, the generic type information is lost due to type erasure, making it impossible to directly access TokenMobieDTO.

To address this issue, you can modify your KafkaConsumerService class to pass the actual class type to the listenX method. Here's how you can do it:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerService {

    @KafkaListener(topics = { "topic-a", "topic-b" }, groupId = "X-consumer")
    public <T> void listenX(KafkaMessageDTO<T> msg) {
        log.info("MSG arrived to consumer");
        T object = msg.getObject();
        // Use 'object' (e.g., cast it to TokenMobieDTO if needed)
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class KafkaMessageDTO<T> {

    @JsonProperty("object")
    private T object;

    @JsonProperty("header")
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    // Getter for 'object'
    public T getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. When I tried to use `T object = msg.getObject();` The object variable contains LinkedHasMap. I can't extract the data

Comment: The JSON object is already deserialized. Casting to a different type cannot change the type of the instance from `LinkedHashMap` to `TokenMobieDTO`.